# What's the difference between fopen and freopen?

Tags: c

Isn't freopen redundant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freopen.html) (see application usage section), `freopen` was originally added to C to facilitate changing `stdin` and `stdout` to binary mode. I suspect if you dig through the ANSI/ISO rationale documents you can find support for that statement. As POSIX documents, this usage is pointless on POSIX systems (where text and binary mode are required to behave identically) and actually harmful due to a bug in the specification which leads to file truncation if followed strictly.

As for practical uses, here are some I can think of:

- replacing `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` before executing external programs - but it's not clear to me whether POSIX requires `freopen` to reuse the same file descriptor number as the original `FILE` had or not, so I'm not sure this is guaranteed to work. I always simply use `open` and `dup2` for this purpose.
- a logging library that takes a `FILE *` from the caller might use `freopen` to put it in append mode to ensure all data is written at the end even if another program writes to the log file.
- if you've already passed around and stored `FILE *` pointers to a number of components in your program and you find yourself later needing to support swapping out the file (for instance, log rotation comes to mind), `freopen` is a lot easier than tracking down everywhere the `FILE *` was stored and hacking in code to update every instance or wrapping the `FILE *` in your own structure that lets you swap it out.

The usefulness of all these is limited by the bad behavior or `freopen` on failure; the `FILE *` becomes invalid and unrecoverable, so if any part of the program might still be using it, you have to find a way to prevent further access or immediately `exit`. Similarly, `freopen` is not thread-safe for the same reason; should it fail, accessing the file from any other thread results in undefined behavior.

Comment: "but it's not clear to me whether POSIX requires freopen to reuse the same file descriptor number as the original FILE had or not". On iOS we have observed that `freopen` does at times assign another fd (not fd 2) to `stderr`. There's no guarantee that the same fd is reused.

Answer (score 6):

No - `freopen()` is not redundant.  It lets you open a file as standard input, for example, which otherwise you could not rely on achieving.

If you have to call a function (for which you don't have the source code, so you can't fix it) that reads on a particular file stream (typically standard input) or writes on a particular file stream (typically standard output) but you don't want the function to read from or write to the file that is connected there in your program, then you can use `freopen()` to fix things so that the function sees what it expects but gets the information from where you want - or writes it where you want.

Comment: But is there any need in changing standard streams which cannot be replaced by dealing with user streams (printf->fprintf)?

Comment: @Vovanium: See my answer for a few uses, although I consider them of questionable value.

Comment: @Vovanium: if you can specify the stream because the called code uses `fprintf()` on the stream you hand it, rather than `printf()`, then there's no reason to use `freopen()`. In 25+ years of C programming, I don't think I've used `freopen()` more than a couple of times, if that. As @R.. pointed out, if you want to do things such as reset standard output back to its original file after the redirection is complete, you drop out of the scope of the C standard into POSIX territory and use file descriptors. For example, `fdopen()` creates a stream for a file descriptor; that I've used quite often.